# How can I get an entity to constantly look at the camera in RealityKit similar to Billboard Constraint from SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit, realitykit

I have an app that I am trying to update from SceneKit to RealityKit, and one of the features that I am having a hard time replicating in RealityKit is making an entity constantly look at the camera. In SceneKit, this was accomplished by adding the following billboard constraints to the node:

```swift
let billboardConstraint = SCNBillboardConstraint()

billboardConstraint.freeAxes = [.X, .Y]
startLabelNode.constraints = [billboardConstraint]
```

Which would allow the startLabelNode to freely rotate so that it was constantly facing the camera without the startLabelNode changing its position.

However, I can't seem to figure out a way to do this with RealityKit. I have tried the "lookat" method, which doesn't seem to offer the ability to constantly face the camera. Here is a short sample app where I have tried to implement a version of this in RealityKit, but it doesn't offer the ability to have the entity constantly face the camera like it did in SceneKit:

```swift
import UIKit
import RealityKit
import ARKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSessionDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var arView: ARView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        arView.session.delegate = self
        arView.environment.sceneUnderstanding.options = []
        arView.debugOptions.insert(.showSceneUnderstanding) // Display a debug visualization of the mesh.
        arView.renderOptions = [.disablePersonOcclusion, .disableDepthOfField, .disableMotionBlur] // For performance, disable render options that are not required for this app.
        arView.automaticallyConfigureSession = false
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        if ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.supportsSceneReconstruction(.mesh) {
            configuration.sceneReconstruction = .mesh
        } else {
            print("Mesh Classification not available on this device")
            configuration.worldAlignment = .gravity
            configuration.planeDetection = [.horizontal, .vertical]
        }
        configuration.environmentTexturing = .automatic
        arView.session.run(configuration)
        
        UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true // Prevent the screen from being dimmed to avoid interrupting the AR experience.
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        let screenWidth = arView.bounds.width
        let screenHeight = arView.bounds.height
        let centerOfScreen = CGPoint(x: (screenWidth / 2), y: (screenHeight / 2))
        
        if let raycastResult = arView.raycast(from: centerOfScreen, allowing: .estimatedPlane, alignment: .any).first
        {
            addStartLabel(at: raycastResult.worldTransform)
        }
    }
    
    func addStartLabel(at result: simd_float4x4) {
        let resultAnchor = AnchorEntity(world: result)
        resultAnchor.addChild(clickToStartLabel())
        arView.scene.addAnchor(resultAnchor)
    }
    
    func clickToStartLabel() -> ModelEntity {
        let text = "Click to Start Here"
        let textMesh = MeshResource.generateText(text, extrusionDepth: 0.001, font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 0.01))
        let textMaterial = UnlitMaterial(color: .black)
        let textModelEntity = ModelEntity(mesh: textMesh, materials: [textMaterial])
        textModelEntity.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
        textModelEntity.position.x -= textMesh.width / 2
        textModelEntity.position.y -= textMesh.height / 2
        
        let planeMesh = MeshResource.generatePlane(width: (textMesh.width + 0.01), height: (textMesh.height + 0.01))
        let planeMaterial = UnlitMaterial(color: .white)
        let planeModelEntity = ModelEntity(mesh: planeMesh, materials: [planeMaterial])
        planeModelEntity.generateCollisionShapes(recursive:true)
        // move the plane up to make it sit on the anchor instead of in the middle of the anchor
        planeModelEntity.position.y += planeMesh.height / 2
        planeModelEntity.addChild(textModelEntity)
        
        // This does not always keep the planeModelEntity facing the camera
        planeModelEntity.look(at: arView.cameraTransform.translation, from: planeModelEntity.position, relativeTo: nil)
                
        return planeModelEntity
    }
}

extension MeshResource {
    var width: Float
    {
        return (bounds.max.x - bounds.min.x)
    }

    var height: Float
    {
        return (bounds.max.y - bounds.min.y)
    }
}
```

Is the lookat function the best way to get the missing feature working in RealityKit or is there a better way to have a Entity constantly face the camera?

Comment: When you say tried lookat - you pointed it at a camera node?

Comment: @Voltan with the example code above, sometimes the entity would point back at the camera, but for the most part it was pointing in what appeared to be a random direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out an answer to my question. Adding the following block of code allowed the entity to constantly look at the camera:

```swift
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
    planeModelEntity.look(at: arView.cameraTransform.translation, from: planeModelEntity.position(relativeTo: nil), relativeTo: nil)
}
```

Comment: It would be a bit more realitykit style to subscribe to the scene update event:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/sceneevents/update

Comment: this code flips the entity backward and it's totally wrong.

Answer (score 0):

k - I haven't messed with RK much, but assuming entity is a scenekit node? - then set constraints on it and it will be forced to face 'targetNode' at all times.  Provide that works the way you want it to, then you may have to experiment with how the node is initially created IE what direction it is facing.

```
func setTarget()
    {
        node.constraints = []
        let vConstraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: targetNode)
        vConstraint.isGimbalLockEnabled = true
        node.constraints = [vConstraint]
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, however, that solution only works in SceneKit, and not in RealityKit. As a side node, Anchors and Entities in RK are not identical to nodes in SK, and neither Entities nor Anchors allow you to add constraints the way that nodes did in SceneKit. As mentioned in the initial post I already have the feature working in SceneKit, and am attempting to update the app to RealityKit. Thank you again for the time and effort put into your response, however I am looking for a solution in RealityKit. If you come across a possible solution please let me know, thanks again!

Comment: No worries, sorry I couldn't help.